# Laravel 8.0 How to eager load when using MorphTo - MorphMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I'm creating a blog with articles, tags, comments and likes. Every article can have tags, comments and likes.
When displaying all articles, I want to eager load its user, tags, comments and likes. The problem is, that likes are in morph relationship with articles and they don't load with articles.

Article.php

```
public function likes(): MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany(Like::class, 'likeable');
}
```

Like.php

```
public function likeable(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

2021_01_26_090103_create_likes_table.php

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id');
        $table->morphs('likeable');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

ArticleController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::with(['user', 'tags', 'comments', 'likes'])->latest()->paginate(10);

    return view('articles.all-articles', compact('articles'));
}
```

[But telescope reports these DB queries:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KfQR.png)

How can I make it to reduce the DB queries?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue and after a little detective work looking at these links

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/28647

https://github.com/tobyzerner/laravel-framework/blob/252872f66cd3b2cde15db92f8489e90a52a25763/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphTo.php

I discovered this is possible, it's just that the "withMorph" from the first link is "morphWith".

So the solution to load the likes (I've used it in my code and it works):

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;

$likes = Like::with(["likeable" => function(MorphTo $morphTo]{
    $morphTo->morphWith([Article::class]);
}]);
```

To load the nested relationships that you want for article, have a look at https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/35190. So I think you should be able to do something like this:

```
$likes = Like::with(["likeable" => function (MorphTo $morphTo) {
    $morphTo->constrain([
        Article::class => function (Builder $query) {
            $query->with(["user", "tags", "comments"]);
        }
    ]);
}])->get();
```

Comment: nice, still working